# Iterate through a Panda's df col to remove str

Tags: python, selenium, beautifulsoup, scripting

I'm trying to solve this issue. Basically my column `'review'` has a bunch of junk HTML stuff which was returned by soup. I am unsure how to remove this and have tried to iterate in various ways.
How would you iterate through the df and replace these values? I would like them blank but I'm using HELLO for test.

```
for index, row in enumerate(df['review']):
    row = df.replace('<div class="text show-more__control">', 'HELLO', inplace=False)
    df['review'] = row
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular string functions such as `replace()` with `DataFrame["columname"].str.replace()`. If you want to replace all values in the column by nothing you can just use `DataFrame["columname"] = ''`.

Comment: HI Joost, this r eturns: AttributeError: Can only use .str accessor with string values!

Comment: My bad! That is probably because there are some non-string values in your column. You could try `DataFrame["columname"].astype(str).str.replace()` to force the variable type to string. I don't have time to test it myself right now though!

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is overkill, because iterating a dataframe with `iterrows` is slow as it iterates through all the rows (with all the columns for each one) and you really only want to apply the replacement to one column.

My advise will be to use a lambda funcion only applied to the column where you want the replacement:

```
df['column'] = df['column'].apply(lambda x: x.replace('replacethis', 'withthis'))
```

Comment: HI Manrique, this code:  df['review'] = df['review'].apply(lambda x: x.replace('<div class="text show-more__control">', '')), will return this code: TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable. Does this need to be in a for loop to replae the str? I'm quite new to python

Comment: that happens because you have null values in the column, you should get rid of them.